# php javascript form with dropdown has %24 in my _GET after I submit

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, forms

I am submitting a form but have some issues with the way the `_GET` is coming back in the URL

Here is the code:

```
index.php/search?stmindate=2013-04-01&stmaxdate=2013-05-31&%24comname=teststring
```

As you can see, between `2013-05-31` and `comname` I get `&%24`
when I try and get it on the other side it wont come back as "teststring" and I assume it's because of this:

```html
<form action="http://<?=$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]?>/index.php/search" method="GET">
  By  Start Date:<br/>
  Min Date:<?= date_input("stmindate", $stmindate, true) ?>
  Max Date:<?= date_input("stmaxdate", $stmaxdate, true) ?> 
  <select name="$comname">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <?
      for ($scan = 0; $scan < count($Companies); $scan++) {
        $ty = $Companies[$scan]['name'];
        $sel = "";
        echo "<option $sel value=\"$ty\">$ty</option>".PHP_EOL;
      }
    ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See your `<select name="$comname">`. You want to take the dollar sign out. %24 is a URL-friendly way of passing that $.  Something that I assume you're not wanting to do.

Comment: This was my issue - I am using a Joomla with a plugin called Jumi.  Jumi treats '$' as a special character and does not output it as a char

Answer (score 1):

http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html

%24 is a dollar sign. It is encoding that into the url string, you need to decode the url to use it, although it seems unlikely you would want to have a $ sign in your URL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Certain characters get encoded for use in a URL. You just need to use `urldecode()` to convert them back.